# Scroll Function When Position is set to Fixed

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

The scrollbar is missing because I have set the position to fixed. Is there any way of getting the scrollbar back. I have checked numerous  solution but none of them work

```
#OuterGallery {
  position:fixed;
  margin: -6px auto 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 675px;
}
```

Thank you very much for ant help you can provide

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this task is via calculating windows height in jquery

[live code](http://jsfiddle.net/5pp4aatk/2/)

```
  if($('#OuterGallery ').height() >= $(window).height()){
      $('body').css({
      height: $('#OuterGallery ').height() + "px"
  })
  }
```